# Java SmartCardIO and JavaFX: NFC On-Tap Functionality or Non-Blocking Waiting for Card Present

Tags: java, asynchronous, nfc, smartcardio

I am trying to accomplish something similar to the post here: [Reading events from javax.smartcardio to detect presence of NFC tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516946/reading-events-from-javax-smartcardio-to-detect-presence-of-nfc-tag), where an action is performed only when an NFC card is tapped to the reader.  Ideally, it would be something like:

```
nfcReader.onTap(()->{
    //do something for that NFC card
})
```

But the SmartCardIO library doesn't have anything like that.

I've tried using the `waitForCardPresent` and `waitForCardAbsent` method (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/CardTerminal.html), which blocks the code until a card is placed/removed, but unfortunately it stops the application while it's waiting. Additionally, I am leveraging a for loop, where unique data is written to each card, and the application is unresponsive until the loop finishes. The logic is as below:

```
for (String customData : data){
     mPresenter.iSmartCardManager.waitForCardPresent();
    // Write customData to card
    mPresenter.iSmartCardManager.waitForCardAbsent();
}
```

During the entire time the code above is executing, I am unable to interface with the application. I am using a JavaFX library (leveraging the TapLinx sample application https://www.mifare.net/developer/home/), and the application is unable to have buttons pressed or logs updated in this non-responsive state. This isn't ideal when I have multiple cards that need to be read/written, with logs that need to be updated for each card.

In order to overcome the blocking nature of the `waitForCardPresent` method, I've tried multiple async options so that the application won't wait on the `waitForCardPresent` method, from this doc: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/core/virtual-threads.html#GUID-C0FEE349-D998-4C9D-B032-E01D06BE55F2.

```
Thread thread = Thread.ofVirtual().start(() -> {
    tagPresent = mPresenter.iSmartCardManager.waitForCardPresent();
    });
thread.join();
```

```
try (ExecutorService myExecutor =
    Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()) {
    Future<?> future = myExecutor.submit(() -> {
    tagPresent = mPresenter.iSmartCardManager.waitForCardPresent();
    });
    future.get();
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.error("Error in thread", e);
}
```

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        tagPresent = mPresenter.iSmartCardManager.waitForCardPresent();

    }
    });
t.start();
```

None of these work, the application still blocks and is unresponsive. Is it possible to have an `onTap()` method that triggers when an NFC tag is placed on the reader? Or, to have a running for-loop that waits for the card to be placed/removed without causing the application to be unresponsive?

Thanks!